# How can I avoid getting a 'Permission needed / Bad Request' dialog when opening an Office 365 Addin?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, manifest, office-addins

My team is in the process of developing an Office 365 add-in, specifically to enable interaction with a hosted web application, and we're encountering a "Permission needed / Bad Request" error that we can't seem to pin down.

**Context:**

Developing and testing the add-in involves configuring an Azure Active Directory v2 application via the management portal as well as (for development purposes) creating an xml manifest file (which is for v1 apps as opposed to the json format for v2) that can be side-loaded via the O365 interface to provide access to our hosted app (currently only xml manifests can be side-loaded). We're still very much in the process of figuring things out in Office 365, as well as Azure/Active Directory and Microsoft Graph, and the documentation is fairly broad and doesn't always seem to be up to date.

**Problem Description:**

One of the problems that we're run into occasionally is encountering a "Bad Request" dialog message (in a browser dialog titled 'Permission needed') that is displayed when clicking the toolbar icon for our add-in. The actual URL being requested is similar to [https://store.office.com/client/consentnotification.aspx](https://store.office.com/client/consentnotification.aspx?client=WAC_Word&cv=16.0.11209.37775&ui=EN-US&appDomain=https://cac-word-edit.officeapps.live.com&rs=developer&notificationType=2&corr=b6ac8001-0dfd-46b8-a1dc-84fb94d083f6&authType=2&appid=f0b307bc-f91d-4b36-a6fb-afbc8822d027&scopes=Files.ReadWrite.All%2CSites.ReadWrite.All%2Coffline_access%2Copenid%2Cprofile%2CUser.Read) with a number of parameters representing our application and it's required permissions. This results in an HTTP 400 with "Bad Request" being the only response content.

This is happening when the user clicks on our add-in in the O365 application toolbar and is occurring at the point where the user would have to authorize permission for the add-in.

This error seems to be related to the application configuration, but we can't seem to sort out how specifically (ie, some developers are encountering it, and others are not. Sometimes it'll show up if we recreate the Azure Active Directory application using one version of portal or another (there are currently two, with the v2 version being in preview).

Can anyone offer suggestions as to what might be causing this or provide information on why this might be occurring? We're not blocked, but it is rather annoying to deal with in development. I've done a fair bit of research trying to sort out why this is happening and I've gone through a number of tutorials/introductions on configuring Azure apps without success.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be related to the Azure Active Directory Application configuration.

For the applications where this was occuring, the AADv2 application manifest was using a `"signInAudience"` value of `"AzureADMyOrg"`. For cases where it was working as expected (ie, properly populating the permission request dialog) the `"signInAudience"` was set to `"AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`.

After some testing, the solution for our particular problem seemed to be either manually editting the AADv2 application manifest (json) to have `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`, or via the Portal by setting the Application's Authentication Supported Account Types setting to be "Accounts in any organizational directory" (this results in a manifest setting of `"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs"` which also seems to work).